# About the 3d Surface

Tags: graphing-functions, 3d, surfaces, geometric-construction, mathematica

I am creating the Enneper Surface in Geogebra with the following equations.

[image: Enneper Surface Equation]

Is the surface or equation correct, and does the Enneper surface look like this?
I'm confused because Wikipedia has a different image of the Enneper surface.
In the equation both parameters $u$ and $v$ are varying from $-5$ to $5$.

[image: Enneper Surface]

Comment: I think you must have misread the equations. For example, Wikipedia's equation for the first component is to be interpreted as $u(1-(u^2/3)+v^2)/3$, not $u(1-u^2/(3+v^2))/3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, the issue is that the equations you used are not quite correct.  It looks like you distributed incorrectly.  They should be

$$\begin{align*}
x &= \frac{u}{3}-\frac{u^{3}}{9}+\frac{v^{2}u}{3}\\
y &= -\frac{v}{3} + \frac{v^{3}}{9} - \frac{vu^{2}}{3}\\
z &= \frac{u^2}{3} - \frac{v^2}{3}
\end{align*}
$$

You can see the difference between the two surfaces on [CalcPlot3D](https://www.monroecc.edu/faculty/paulseeburger/calcnsf/CalcPlot3D/?type=parametric;parametric=2;x=(u)/(3)-(u%5E(3))/(9)+(v%5E(2)u)/(3);y=(-v)/(3)+(v%5E(3))/(9)-(v*u%5E(2))/(3);z=(u%5E2)/3-(v%5E2)/3;visible=true;umin=-2;umax=2;usteps=30;vmin=-2;vmax=2;vsteps=15;alpha=-1;format=normal;constcol=rgb(255,0,0)&type=parametric;parametric=2;x=(u)/(3)-((u%5E(3))/(3+v%5E(2)))/(3);y=(-v)/(3)+(v%5E(3))/(9+3u%5E(2));z=(u%5E2)/3-(v%5E2)/3;visible=true;umin=-3;umax=3;usteps=40;vmin=-3;vmax=3;vsteps=10;alpha=-1;format=normal;constcol=rgb(255,0,0)&type=window;hsrmode=3;nomidpts=true;anaglyph=-1;center=-0.9474579824393022,9.315705613521823,3.509978959154494,1;focus=0,0,0,1;up=0.10547209065751814,-0.3412059675424394,0.9340525283974985,1;transparent=false;alpha=140;twoviews=false;unlinkviews=false;axisextension=0.7;xaxislabel=x;yaxislabel=y;zaxislabel=z;edgeson=true;faceson=true;showbox=false;showaxes=false;showticks=false;perspective=true;centerxpercent=0.5;centerypercent=0.5;rotationsteps=30;autospin=true;xygrid=false;yzgrid=false;xzgrid=false;gridsonbox=false;gridplanes=false;gridcolor=rgb(128,128,128);xmin=-2;xmax=2;ymin=-2;ymax=2;zmin=-2;zmax=2;xscale=1;yscale=1;zscale=1;zcmin=-4;zcmax=4;zoom=0.833333;xscalefactor=1;yscalefactor=1;zscalefactor=1).

To get an plot like the one on Wikipedia it is easier to use the polar parameterization:

$$\begin{align*}
x &= r\cos(\phi) - \frac{1}{3}r^{3}\cos(3\phi)\\
y &= -\frac{1}{3}r\left[3\sin(\phi) + r^{2}\sin(3\phi)\right]\\
z &= r^{2}\cos(2\phi)
\end{align*}
$$

Plotting this with $r\in [0,2]$ and $\phi \in [-\pi,\pi]$ will produce a plot similar to the one on Wikipedia.  Again, you can see this on [CalcPlot3D](https://www.monroecc.edu/faculty/paulseeburger/calcnsf/CalcPlot3D/?type=parametric;parametric=2;x=ucos(v)-1/3*u%5E3*cos(3v);y=-1/3*u*(3sin(v)+u%5E2*sin(3v));z=u%5E2*cos(2v);visible=true;umin=0;umax=2;usteps=40;vmin=-pi;vmax=pi;vsteps=40;alpha=-1;format=normal;constcol=rgb(255,0,0)&type=window;hsrmode=3;nomidpts=true;anaglyph=-1;center=-5.962478265690356,-7.965661246744832,0.9985458593755886,1;focus=0,0,0,1;up=0.00487592222270547,0.14556063130021304,0.9893373176010101,1;transparent=false;alpha=140;twoviews=false;unlinkviews=false;axisextension=0.7;xaxislabel=x;yaxislabel=y;zaxislabel=z;edgeson=true;faceson=true;showbox=false;showaxes=false;showticks=false;perspective=true;centerxpercent=0.5;centerypercent=0.5;rotationsteps=30;autospin=true;xygrid=false;yzgrid=false;xzgrid=false;gridsonbox=false;gridplanes=false;gridcolor=rgb(128,128,128);xmin=-2;xmax=2;ymin=-2;ymax=2;zmin=-2;zmax=2;xscale=1;yscale=1;zscale=1;zcmin=-4;zcmax=4;zoom=0.573333;xscalefactor=1;yscalefactor=1;zscalefactor=1)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for spotting the error. Can you suggest the range of u and u so it can look like a surface on Wikipedia

Comment: @PankajSolanki see my edits.

Comment: Thank you very much.